# Validating image and storing image in specific folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am validating and storing image using my Controller.

When I validate image form is not stored in database but when I comment validation it stores in database.

**FrontController.php**

```
public function StorePost(Request $request)
{
    $formInput = $request->except('image');

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'       => 'required',
        'name'        => 'required',
        'email'       => 'required|email',
        'contact'     => 'required',
        'model'       => 'required',
        'city'        => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image'       => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
    ]);

    //image upload

    $image = $request->image;

    if($image){
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('images', $imageName);
        $formInput['image'] = $imageName;
    }

   Post::create($formInput);

   $posts = Post::all();

   return view('ad.ad', compact('name', 'posts'));
}
```

Comment: Please include your model and `html` code

Comment: class Post extends Model
{

    public $table = 'post';

    public $fillable = ['name','title','email','contact','model','color','city','price','description','image'];


    public function ad(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Ad::class)->withPivot('name','title','contact','model','city','price','image');;
    }
}

Comment: Please edit the question instead.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a54cuwZ

Comment: https://imgur.com/e2LmcN9

Comment: https://imgur.com/wKUFK6T

Comment: Edit is asking for more text which is annoying.

Comment: So from what you've shown us, validation is failing for your image. What is the problem, exactly? Are you [showing validation errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) on the form?